# When a power supply has multiple stated output parameters, are those discrete output settings or some possible settings along a continuum?

Tags: charger

Let's take my 30W USB-C Apple power supply as an example: https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MR2A2LL/A/30w-usb-c-power-adapter.
Printed on it are 4 outputs:

- 20V / 1.5A
- 15V / 2A
- 9V / 3A
- 5V / 3A

Are these fundamentally discrete charging profiles between which the power supply can switch or is its output a continuous spectrum of voltage and amperage determined by the device drawing the power and the printed outputs are examples of possible output profiles?

Comment: Note that these are not **charging profiles**, they are just fixed voltage outputs. You can't connect these voltages directly to a battery and expect it to charge properly.

Answer (score 1):

Best to read a summary of USB-C Power Delivery spec.

These are discrete voltage output levels.  The amount of available current is specified for each discrete voltage setting.

Note that the default voltage / current is 5V @ whatever current is specified.  Higher voltage output is negotiated when the power supply is connected to the device being powered.

[Edit]

Here is a link to a ST PDF file that talks about USB-C and Power Delivery (PD)  [ST PDF file](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/sales_and_marketing/presentation/product_presentation/group0/5a/b1/8e/6c/2b/0d/46/3c/Apec/files/APEC_2016_USB_Power.pdf/_jcr_content/translations/en.APEC_2016_USB_Power.pdf)

Comment: OK so it sounds like if it is plugged into a "dumb" non-USB-3.0 device, it will default to charge at 5V and whatever current is drawn by the device. But if it is plugged into a USB-3.0 capable device, then the device can request one of those discrete higher voltage profiles? Correct me if I'm wrong about any of that.

Comment: Close.  I do not believe that USB-3.x can request any higher voltage above 5 Vdc.  I **think** that only USB-C can request the higher voltages.  That said: I could easily be wrong.  Bottom line is that the power brick defaults to a voltage that won't damage anything.